# Paypal MPL Delayed Chained Payment

Tags: android, paypal

Does MPL Support DELAYED Chained Payments in Android and iOS? I can't find an example of this.

Any help you can provide is very appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afraid that cannot use delayed chained payment even though MPL is built based on Adaptive Payment that is able to make a delayed chained payment.
Because in MPL SDK PayPal does not provide method to set "actionType" as "PAY_PRIMARY" that does control whether to make delayed chained payment.

Comment: I am facing same issues and didn't founded any clue regarding delay payment

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issues using Mobile Payment Library(MPL) where i can able to integrate chain payment but payment transfer immediately on secondly user without delay or approvement.
I have discuss with PayPal support team and they told me that Delay chain payment is not still supported by Mobile Payment Library (MPL).

So i tried following method and its works. Now payment will transfer to primary user and when i want then its transfer to secondary user.

For android you can use similar functionality of webview

First create transaction with all parameter like amount,receipts etc and get PAY_KEY for the transaction from backend (PHP,JAVA,RUBY or any) with the help of reference paypal link :- Step 2 : https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/php?success=true
Then with paykey we can make payment only in webview so Open UIWebView in ViewController with following URL

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=%@&expType=mini",@"[PAY_KEY]"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

[webView loadRequest:strURL];
```

Web view Delegate Method

```
#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegate
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if([[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/closewindow"])
    {
        [self validatePayment];
        return YES;
    }            
    return YES;
}
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    if (!actView.isAnimating) {
        [actView startAnimating];
    }
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [actView stopAnimating];
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [actView stopAnimating];
}
```

The finally on close the popup you can validate payment with the PAYKEY
from backend by step 4 in https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/php?success=true

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the MPL (Mobile Payment Library) uses the [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/).  The [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) is what's used to submit payments, and that's where you can setup the payment as a [delayed chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/).

Comment: How to configure Pay API on MPL. Can you describe more brief